# Memory leak in a delegate method

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, mvp

I am following MVP architecture for developing an iOS app.The app is quite simple in which onViewDidLoad() I call a web service which returns me some data and I display that data in a table view.

ViewController:

```
class A : UIViewController{

var presenter : MyPresenter?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     presenter = MyPresenter(delegate:self)
     presenter.callWS()
  }

}
extension A : Mydelegate{

   func onSuccess(){

       //this doesnt allow my viewcontroller to deint
       tablview.delegate=self
       tableview.datasource=self
       tableview.reloadData()
}

}

protocol MyDelegate : class{

func onSuccess()

}

class MYPresenter {

 weak var delegate : MyDelegate?

    init(MyDelegate) {
        self.delegate=delegate
    }

    func callWS(){

       delegate.onSuccess()

       }

}
```

This onSucces of MyDelegate does not allow my A viewcontroller to deint
Please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an actual code? I believe that in this simplified example some details could have been omitted.

Comment: @Mr.Hedgehog its is kind of the same sir but if I comment the table view part from the onSuccess() the memory leaks doesn't occur

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly modified version of your code and run it in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class A : UITableViewController {

    var presenter : MyPresenter?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        presenter = MyPresenter(delegate:self)
        presenter?.callWS()

        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissOnTap))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    func dismissOnTap() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    deinit {
        print("Bye VC")
    }
}

extension A : MyDelegate {

    func onSuccess(){

        //this doesnt allow my viewcontroller to deint
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

protocol MyDelegate : class {

    func onSuccess()

}

class MyPresenter {

    weak var delegate : MyDelegate?

    init(delegate: MyDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func callWS() {
        delegate?.onSuccess()
    }

    deinit {
        print("Bye")
    }

}

class B: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showOnTap))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    func showOnTap() {
        let vc = A(style: .plain)
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }

}

let b = B()
b.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 600)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = b.view
```

And everything is deallocating properly. I guess the retain cycle is somewhere else and it's hard to find based on provided code.